# Как найти сумму двух элементов массива, максимально близкую к нулю в C++?

Tags: c++, массивы, алгоритм

я начинающий в C++ и не могу найти решение ...

```
#include <iostream>
 
int main()
{   
    unsigned int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    int* arr = new int[N];
    int res = 0;
    int index1 = 0, index2 = 1;
    res = arr[0] + arr[1]; 
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
      std::cin >> arr[i];
    for (int j =  i + 1; j < N; ++j)
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] < res)
        {
            res = arr[i] + arr[j];
            index1 = i;
            index2 = j;
        }
    }  
 std::cout << arr[index1] << " " << arr[index2];
}
```

*Примеры*

**Входные данные**

```
5 1 2 3 4 5
```

**Результат работы**

```
1 2
```

**Входные данные**

```
10 -100 100 -753 999 -159 9 45 7 -8 -1
```

**Результат работы**

```
-100 100
```

**Входные данные**

```
3 0 1 -2
```

**Результат работы**

```
0 1
```

Comment: другими словами, вам надо найти суммы всех пар и определить, какая из сумм минимальная по модулю.

Comment: Может, отсортировать, и для каждого значения искать бинарным поиском подходящее? O(n lg n)?

Answer (score 0):

Вынесите ввод данных отдельно от обработки, иначе на каждом шаге ещё нечего обсчитывать.

```
for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) 
      std::cin >> arr[i];
int res = 0;
int index1 = 0, index2 = 1;
res = arr[0] + arr[1]; 

 for (int i = 1; i < N; i++) {
    for (int j =  i + 1; j < N; ++j)
        if (arr[i] + arr[j] < res)
        {
            res = arr[i] + arr[j];
            index1 = i;
            index2 = j;
        }
    }
```

Другой вариант - внутренний цикл должен проходить по началу массива (от нуля до i-1), а не по концу.